# Angular - a component loads before a service fetches necessary information

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I'm currently struggling with observables. I think I don't understand the main concepts of rxjs properly. Here's what I'm trying to achieve.

In my Angular app there's a `/product/:slug` route which leads to `ProductShowComponent`. To display all the necessary information I first need to fetch all the products from the API with my `ProductsService`. The point is, the products can possibly be fetched after the component loads (e.g. when a user refreshes the page on `/product/:slug`).

What I'm trying to do is implementing an `onReady` method in `productsService`, subscribe to it in `ProductShowComponent` and display the product once the information is fetched from the API. I thought it might be possible if the `onReady` method returns an `Observable` that watches for the changes of `productsService.ready` value but I have no idea how to do that or if it's possible at all. Maybe there's a better way to do that? Any ideas?

**product-show.component.ts**

```
(...)

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.productsService.onReady().subscribe(() => {
      this.product = this.productsService.get(params['productSlug'], 'slug')
    })
  })
}

(...)
```

**products.service.ts**

```
(...)

constructor(
  private appClient: AppClient
) {
  this.fetchAll().subscribe((products: Product[]) => {
    this.products = products
    this.ready = true
  })
}

(...)

public onReady(): Observable<any> {
  if (!this.ready) {
    // return an observable that watches for changes of value of this.ready
  } else {
    return Observable.of(null)
  }
}

(...)
```

Comment: Have you considered using a route resolver guard? It ensures some data is present before loading the component. Documents: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track but I'd like to add two points.  You could solve your problem with either one but I think both are valid.

## Services should expose state through observables

In your example your service is storing the current projects and then exposing that non-observable state.  So for example,  you could have...

**product-show.component.ts**

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.productsService.get(params['productSlug']).subscribe(product =>
      this.product = product;
    });
  });
}
```

**products.service.component.ts**

```
constructor(
  private appClient: AppClient
) {
  this.products = this.fetchAll().publish();
  this.productsSub = this.products.connect();
}

get(productId: string, idType: string) {
  return this.products.map(products => {
    return this.getProductFromProducts(products, productId, idType);
  });
}
```

Now you don't really  need to bother with a ready flag because you can call get as soon as the service is constructed.

The other advantage is that if something caused your available products set to change then your component would update automatically (provided your service was extended to go refetch the data on a change).

## Use Subjects for Dynamic Application State

Now lets assume that you really do need the ready flag.  For example, maybe you have a several components that display some "data loading" flag until all of the initial application data (which might come from several services) is loaded.  However, for example purposes we will just solve your initial problem with a subject.  So leaving your component as you had it we can modify your service to...

**products.service.component.ts**

```
constructor(
  private appClient: AppClient
) {
  this.ready = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  this.fetchAll().subscribe((products: Product[]) => {
    this.products = products
    this.ready.next(true);
  });
}
```

Since subjects are observables you don't need `onReady` you can just subscribe directly to `ready`.

Comment: Thanks for your input! It looks like subjects are exactly what I was looking for. I'll keep in mind the advantages of the other solution, tho.